# How to convert snake case to dash case in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know I can convert `"hello_world"` to `"hello-world"` by calling `"hello_world".gsub('_', '-')`. But is there a string method for this built into Rails, something equivalent to [underscore](https://devdocs.io/rails%7E5.2/string#method-i-underscore)? Sometimes it's difficult to find such methods if you don't know the name!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`dasherize`](https://devdocs.io/rails%7E5.2/string#method-i-dasherize) right there on the same page

```
"hello_world".dasherize # => 'hello-world'
```